# How to start an activity with a button from a fragment?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-studio, findviewbyid

I have a fragment that has a floating action button that I want to start an activity when pressed. Here is the code for the fragment I want to launch from:

```
package com.nhscoding.safe2tell;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class LEARN extends Fragment {


    View rootview;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_learn, container, false);
        return rootview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Button subTip = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.subTip);
        subTip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(),SUBMIT_TIP.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public static LEARN newInstance() {
        LEARN fragment = new LEARN();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;


    }
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }



//public class Stuff extends Activity {
//    Button submit_tip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_tip);
//    submit_tip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//        public void onClick(View v) {
//            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SUBMIT_TIP.class);
//            startActivityForResult(intent,0);
//        }
}
```

This returns an error on findViewById because it cannot be used in a fragment, only an activity. Do I need to change this to an activity or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a reference to a `View` in the `onCreate()` method of a `Fragment` will not work, because the `Fragment`'s layout has not yet been inflated.

All you need to do is replace

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Button subTip = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.subTip);
    subTip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(),SUBMIT_TIP.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);
        }
    });
}
```

with this:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    final FloatingActionButton subTip = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.subTip);
    subTip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(),SUBMIT_TIP.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);
        }
    });
}
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: I did that, and now it crashes

Comment: logcat: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Uy5fSOob1xwa28p3-lvLYaUWmsJveGe39qD3rRGy-94/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user3566841: where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `rootview` for accessing Button from Fragment layout:

```
    final Button subTip = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.subTip);
```

**Note:** `getActivity()` return main Activity context in which current Fragment is added so if we call `rootview.findViewById` means we are accessing view from Activity layout instead of Fragment

Comment: @user3566841 : As in log use `FloatingActionButton` instead of Button

Answer (score 0):

you can use this . you can  get your current activity by `getActivity` .

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated (View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState){
final Button b= (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(),yourActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,0);
    }
}

);
}
```